# Multiple clipboard hotkeys within OneNote

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys, clipboard, microsoft-onenote

In OneNote, I can copy my pen's drawings and repaste it in. When repasted in, the stroke properties are maintained, so I can erase and edit whatever I need.

This is very helpful when writing math equations in onenote, because I can copy an equation as the next line and then re-edit it. Usually looking something like this:

[image]

One thing that would be a big help is if I could copy multiple different things as hotkeys. This way I can even save common handwritten symbols or equations, so I can avoid writing them down each time.

A long time ago I used to use AutoHotkey occasionally (although now I never use it, even though I should.) Googling around, it seems like there's a simple autohotkey script that can do multiple custom clipboards.

This version doesn't work for me for two reasons:

1. It's buggy and only works some of the time.
2. When it does work, the data that gets stored to the clipboard is an un-editable *image*, and not the editable strokes I'm looking for.

Any ideas for how to handle this problem? I can imagine that there's a way of grabbing specifically the one-note info from the clipboard, but I'm not enough of an expert to know how to do it.

Comment: Did you try to use [Microsoft Office Clipboard](https://www.howtogeek.com/269146/how-to-use-microsoft-offices-built-in-clipboard/) which can accomodate up to 24 clippings? Yeah, you can hardly preserve application-specific clipboard content in general clipboard utilities. If the Office itself does not support what you expect using its own Clipboard extension mentioned above, then you may be out of luck.

Comment: In the latest Windows, there is also a clipboard history available via Win+V shortcut. Check it out.